# canvas issue on chrome mobile

Tags: html5-canvas, rendering

I´m writing a component for capturing signatures on mobile devices.
My code is working fine on both iOS and Android. But not on all devices.

For example I was testing on an Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 and everything works as expected.
I tested in Android Browser, Chrome, FF, Opera and Maxthon. No issues.

Now testing on my Galaxy Note 2 I´m wondering why it does not work in Chrome. There are no errors. My javascript is working fine. But input is not rendered to my canvas.
In Android Browser it works as expected.

Any ideas?

Here are my handler:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var startedPainting = false;

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", handleStart, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMove, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", handleEnd, false);
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
canvas.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, false);

function handleStart(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();

      startedPainting = true;
      var el = $("#canvas").get(0);
      var ctx = el.getContext("2d");
      ctx.lineWidth = 3;
      var touches = evt.changedTouches;

      if (touches) {
        ctx.moveTo(touches[0].pageX - el.offsetLeft, touches[0].pageY - el.offsetTop);
        for (var i=0; i<touches.length; i++) {
            ctx.lineTo(touches[i].pageX - el.offsetLeft, touches[i].pageY - el.offsetTop);
          }
      }
      else{
            ctx.moveTo(evt.pageX - el.offsetLeft, evt.pageY - el.offsetTop);
            ctx.lineTo(evt.pageX - el.offsetLeft, evt.pageY - el.offsetTop);
      }           
      ctx.stroke();
    }


function handleMove(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();

      if (startedPainting) {
          var el = $("#canvas").get(0);
          var ctx = el.getContext("2d");
          ctx.lineWidth = 3;
          var touches = evt.changedTouches;

          if (touches) {
            for (var i=0; i<touches.length; i++) {           
                ctx.lineTo(touches[i].pageX - el.offsetLeft, touches[i].pageY - el.offsetTop);
              }
          }
          else{
                ctx.lineTo(evt.pageX - el.offsetLeft, evt.pageY - el.offsetTop);
          }
          ctx.stroke();       
      }
    }

function handleEnd(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      startedPainting = false;
      var el = $("#canvas").get(0);
      var ctx = el.getContext("2d");
      ctx.lineWidth = 3;
      var touches = evt.changedTouches;

      if (touches) {
            for (var i=0; i<touches.length; i++) {
                ctx.lineTo(touches[i].pageX - el.offsetLeft, touches[i].pageY - el.offsetTop);
              }
      }
      else{
        ctx.lineTo(evt.pageX - el.offsetLeft, evt.pageY - el.offsetTop);
      }
      ctx.stroke();       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is a GPU driver issue. Google is aware of the issue, and there has been discussion in case #231082 over on the Chromium issue database.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=231082

It looks like the issue has been fixed and is (as of 26 Jun 2013) currently in beta.